# Error /bin/bash: line 1: nil: command not found

Tags: python, commands, exec-path, error

I have the following code to auto format python code using autopep8:

```
(defcustom python-autopep8-path (executable-find "autopep8")
  "autopep8 executable path."
  :group 'python
  :type 'string)

(defun python-autopep8 ()
  "Automatically formats Python code to conform to the PEP 8 style guide.
$ autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <filename>"
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
    (shell-command 
     (format "%s --in-place --aggressive %s" python-autopep8-path
             (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))
    (revert-buffer t t t)))

(bind-key "C-c C-a" 'python-autopep8)
```

When I am setting up emacs and use for the first time it works perfectly, but then when I close emacs with `M-x kill-emacs` and re open emacs again and try to use it, I get the error: `/bin/bash: line 1: nil: command not found`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393628/emacs-shell-command-not-found) on Stackoverflow where that person gets a similar error. They solved it apparently by setting the proper path to the variable `PATH` using `M-x setenv`. I was trying to do the same, but I am not sure what path to use and I tried different paths but kept getting the same error. I'd appreciate any help. I suspect the solution will be simple, but I just don't know it.

Comment: What is the path to the executable autopep8? Is it on the path in your shell startup files? Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using fedora 35. Let me see how to find that path.

Comment: When I run ```echo $PATH``` I get ```/home/carlos/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/bin:/home/carlos/.local/bin:/home/carlos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/loca\
l/sbin:/usr/sbin```

Comment: What is the value in emacs of python-autopep8-path after reopening?

Comment: `/usr/loca\ l/sbin` looks bad.

Comment: Where is autopeop8 - the path looks odd with the space in it that ought to be removed but should not be the issue

Comment: What does `which autopep8` say?

Comment: ```which autopep8``` says: ```/home/carlos/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/bin/autopep8```.

Comment: You can then `M-x customize-option` for `python-autopep8-path` and give it the same value.

Comment: I *suspect* the root of your problem will be that the process which adds `/home/carlos/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/bin` to your `PATH` is part of your shell config, and that you're not starting Emacs from a shell.  I've seen people having that issue on many an occasion.

Comment: You could also customize `C-h v exec-path`.  If you need `C-h v process-environment` to have been updated though, that's slightly fiddlier (`setenv` is the easiest way, but you'd want to call it in your init file if you wanted to make that permanent).

Comment: I am getting a weird error. I copy and paste the output of ```which autopep8```, but I get the error: ```Symbol's value as variable is void: /home/carlos/\.virtualenvs/virtual_env/bin/autopep8``` . It's adding an extra ```\```, which I suppose happens because of the dot.

Comment: You'll need to double-quote that value to make it a string -- Emacs thinks you're giving it the name of a variable.

Comment: This wouldn't normally be needed as the defcustom is defined as a `string` -- but the original value was the `nil` symbol which is not a string, and that has consequently messed up the customize form for you, causing you to need to enter the string using double-quoted string read syntax.

Comment: You can change your code to this: `(defcustom python-autopep8-path (or (executable-find "autopep8") "autopep8")` so that if `executable-find` can't find it, you still get a valid string value.

Comment: It works like a charm. I'll post the final code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @phils who helped to come up with this piece of code that works:

```
(defcustom python-autopep8-path (or (executable-find "autopep8") "autopep8")
  "autopep8 executable path."
  :group 'python
  :type 'string)

(defun python-autopep8 ()
  "Automatically formats Python code to conform to the PEP 8 style guide.
$ autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive <filename>"
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
    (shell-command 
     (format "%s --in-place --aggressive %s" python-autopep8-path
             (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))
    (revert-buffer t t t)))

(bind-key "C-c C-a" 'python-autopep8)
```